# Is there any way to access the heart rate sensor from the Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

Being that Apple is gearing the watch as a health device, is it possible for developers to get the heart rate? I did not see documentation for the heart rate sensor. I'm not sure how they plan for third party health apps to do much without this basic piece of data.

Comment: Yes, you can access with watchos 2, here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002910/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-accelerometer-from-the-apple-watch/30985555#30985555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Direct access to the Apple Watch sensors (which includes the heart rate monitor) is not possible.

As always, if this is something you'd like, please file a request for it at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Don't see an option for WatchKit in the bug reporter..

Comment: Thanks, I've let the Bug Reporter team know about that. In the meantime, file it under the iOS SDK and we'll figure it out. Thanks! :)

Comment: I just filed the bug report, hope you see it! (if you work there) Thanks!

Comment: @troop231 Thank you! Do you have the 8 digit bug number handy?

Comment: it is: 19019132. And I swear I've talked to you on the phone before if you work for Apple Developer relations

Comment: You could use HealthKit to indirectly access the user's heart rate if they've already recorded it, but it doesn't sound like that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Anything that you retrieve from HealthKit would not be "realtime" data, which I assumed is what the OP was going for.

Comment: @DaveDeLong will access to the Apple Watch heart rate monitor ever be possible?  Or is it just currently unavailable?

Comment: @Alan_s Sorry, but I can't comment or speculate on that. :)

Comment: @Alan - if we look at the phone then yes. Apple will open sensors up when they have satisfied themselves that APIs are in place to stop developers doing stupid things like running the HR sensor permanently and give users clear control over their data.