# Is Apple Watch accelerometer giving proper data?

Tags: swift, apple-watch

Is this normal, or there is still no access to accelerometer (you can use accelerometer, but you don't have real data which are different as you move with Wathces)?

I've tried getting data by this code:

[Is there any way to access the accelerometer from the Apple Watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002910/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-accelerometer-from-the-apple-watch)

The values are not static, there is some noise, but when I move with Watches (real device), the values are still about 0, 0, -1 (x, y, z). For example (I can't send pictures) 0.01776, -0.02107, -0.99559.

I am moving with my Watches in all axis, but raw data are still the same. I write output in labels on Watches.

Comment: Why do you refer to "Watches" as a thing, and not just the thing you're running your code on? Are you doing something unusual and not testing the software on the device?

Comment: @iAdjunct Is this a problem? No, I am not doing anything unusual. Maybe just my english is bad and I've described my issue in wrong way.

Comment: It's not a problem except that we don't know what you're doing. Are you running your code ON a watch, looking at its debugger output? Or do you have some other weird setup?

Comment: @iAdjunct Oh, yes, you are right. I am running code on a Watch. And on Watches I have three labels with axis so I can see data.

Comment: Why is "Watches" a proper noun? It sounds like you are referring to something specific, as opposed to just "your watch."

Comment: @Boomerange What values would you expect? Basically, you're given g forces for the current orientation.

Comment: Do you use watchOS 2 ?

Comment: @Eiko I expect values like from iPhone. So if I put Watches by display down (turn them by 180° on x axis, I expect 0,0,1 (not 0,0,-1). But Watches are displaying still 0,0,-1.

Comment: @Qbyte Yes, I have watchOS 2 beta 3.

Comment: Then flip the watch around the appropriate axis and it should show 0,0,1

Comment: @Eiko As I wrote, Watches still shows 0, 0, -1. No matter what position. Once again, watches are displaying only values about 0, 0, -1.

Comment: It is strange, even gyroscope is not working. There is nobody with Apple Watch to try my code? This is useful for Apple Watch programmers: https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is, I had a test project and added MotionKit which, I believed, was CoreMotion for Apple Watch. As soon as I started new project, the accelerometer worked. Thanks everybody for answers.

Comment: Is that an official apple thing or one of the open projects on github?

Comment: @Ondrej: It is an open project.